# Grafana - How to build a singlestat with a percentage uptime

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm collecting a series of http response time of a web site, i'd would create a single stat to display the uptime of the web service based on the interval of the dashboard (in case the response time has been above a X ms or any datapoints aren't available)

Is there a way to generate a singlestat in grafana with a percentage of this kind of data?

For example, my data is stored in a influxdb as:

```
time                | host   |http_response_code | response_time | url
--------------------| ------ |------------------ |-------------- |----
1485441250000000000 | Server1|             200   | 0.005797832   | url1
```

UPDATE FOR MICHAEL QUESTION:

The metric used is built-in in telegraf inputs as:

```
# # HTTP/HTTPS request given an address a method and a timeout
[[inputs.http_response]]
  address = "http://www.customurl.com/pingpage.html"
  response_timeout = "10s"
  method = "GET"
```

I guess the point in line protocol is:

```
http_response,
host=hosttag,
http_response_code=200,
method=GET,
server=servertag response_time=0,01202
```

Comment: Can you include an example point in line protocol?

Comment: Just updated for Michael

Comment: Cool. I understand a little more, but what number are you trying to get? Like what does the number you're trying to get represent?

Comment: For example, every 5 min I have a metric about the response time, in case the web site is offline I should have an empty datapoint.
I would represent a single stat in percentage about the uptime of the website in terms of SLA.
Just doing another example, if i have 12 requests in one hour, and 2 of them didn't returned, I should have a 83% uptime in the last hour.
The time range examined should be determinated by the time range set in the grafana dashboard.